# If $D=0.a_{1}a_{2}a_{1}a_{2}a_{1} \cdots \times A =I$. Find $A$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

$D$ is a real number with non-terminating digits $a_{1}$ , $a_{2}$ after the decimal point. Let $D=0.a_{1}a_{2}a_{1}a_{2}a_{1} \cdots$ with $a_{1}$ , $a_{2}$ not both zero. Which of the following numbers when multiplied by $D$ will necessarily give an integer.

1. $33$
2. $288$
3. $18$
4. $198$.

This was contest problem, but how is this possible, please explain with appropriate answer, and make title more appealing if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$D= 0.\overline{a_1a_2} =0.a_{1}a_{2}a_{1}a_{2}a_{1} \cdots = \dfrac{10a_1+a_2}{99}\qquad$
([see this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1991717/what-is-the-least-possible-denominator-of-such-a-positive-rational-number/1991837#1991837))

The answer is $``4.\;\; 198."$

Answer (score 0):

We have $D=0.a_{1}a_{2}a_{1}a_{2}a_{1} \cdots$ which makes us write $D=0.a_{1}a_{2}(1+0.01+0.01^2\cdots)$. We know that the term in the bracket is an infinite G.P with starting term 1 and ratio as 0.01. Using the formula=$\frac{a}{1-r}$ for an infinite G.P where a is starting term and r is the ratio we have the sum as $\frac{1}{0.99}$. Then, D=$a_{1}a_{2}(0.01)(\frac{1}{0.99}) =\frac{a_{1}a_{2}}{99}.$ This means that D should be an integral multiple of 99. So, among the given options 198 is the correct choice.